# Django structure

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, structure

I really need a way to print the structure of my Django app

So I have an almost finished app and I need to print something like this:

```
~/projects/project_name/

docs/               # documentation
scripts/
  manage.py         # installed to PATH via setup.py
project_name/       # project dir (the one which django-admin.py creates)
  apps/             # project-specific applications
    accounts/       # most frequent app, with custom user model
    __init__.py
    ...
  settings/         # settings for different environments, see below
    __init__.py
    production.py
    development.py
    ...
        
  __init__.py       # contains project version
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
static/             # site-specific static files
templates/          # site-specific templates
tests/              # site-specific tests (mostly in-browser ones)
tmp/                # excluded from git
setup.py
requirements.txt
requirements_dev.txt
pytest.ini
```

Is this possible? I only can find a way to create an app based in other structure. I need the same but in the other way... Getting the structure of my app...

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What is the purpose of your question ? Do you need to achieve this in Python ? Does it have to be achieved in the Django app itself ? Otherwise, can it be performed by a linux command ?

Answer (score 0):

Within the command line (ensure you're in the project repository).

Then simply execute:

```
tree
```

This should return the folder structure you're referring to.